# how to handle multiple developer environment in web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5, asp.net-web-api2

So lets say we have three environment dev, qa and prod. In addition to that, all developers have their own environment. How do you manage connection string or app setting for each env?

I believe for dev, qa and prod i can use web.config transformations (lot of resources online on how to do it). But i am stumped on how to setup developers settings in a manageable way. one way we've been doing is

```
--web.config--
<add name="oracle_user1" connectionString="Data Source=DevDB;..." providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
<add name="oracle_user2" connectionString="Data Source=QaDB;..." providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
<add name="oracle_dev" connectionString="Data Source=DevDB;..." providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
<add name="oracle_qa" connectionString="Data Source=QaDB;..." providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
<add name="oracle_prod" connectionString="Data Source=ProdDB;..." providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
--code--
string conString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oracle_" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppEnv")]
```

Is this the standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we handle this is to use a separate config for connection strings, which is excluded from the repository.

In Web.Config, the connection strings section looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="Config\ConnectionStrings.config" />
```

The config folder has two files:

- ConnectionStrings.Config
- ConnectionStrings.Config.Template

The template file consists of this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="[...]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Each developer copies this to a new file named `ConnectionStrings.config` and edits the connection string to reflect their machine.

You could use the same method to also externalize other config settings.

Comment: hmm, i like it but when ever we want to deploy we will have to manually remember to set all the config?

Comment: @surya No, you can use SlowCheetah for web.config transformations. This will allow you to transform your config file automatically based on the build configuration.  So, if you create a release build, it would replace your connection strings node with the connection string for your production server (as well as anything else in your web.config - app settings, mail servers, etc)